# How to fix : Command not found - Git Alias

Tags: git, powershell, git-alias

I'm trying to setup a git alias to list all files that are marked 'assume-unchanged' with this command:

```
git ls-files -v | sls -pattern ^h -casesensitive
```

When i use this command directly in powershell it works as expected but as an alias i get the error :

```
PS C:\git\sim> git unchanged
git ls-files -v | sls -pattern ^h -casesensitive: sls: command not found
```

In my .gitconfig file i have

```
# ALIASES   
[alias]
  unchanged = !git ls-files -v | sls -pattern ^h -casesensitive
```

I have tried different variations...
 with '!' exclamation and without,
wrapped in double/single quotes and without.

If i remove the end part it works as expected e.g.

```
[alias]
  unchanged = !git ls-files -v
```

So i assume something is wrong with the syntax in the second half of the command?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a Git alias with `!` in order to have it execute a *shell command* (rather than the default behavior of passing *arguments* to `git`), Git uses:

- on Unix-like platforms: the *default shell*, `/bin/sh`
- on Windows: the Bash version that comes bundled with Git

Therefore, **in order to define a Git alias that executes a *PowerShell* command, you must invoke [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) explicitly** and pass the command to it via the `-c` parameter:

Here's a full example; note that it assumes PowerShell *Core*; for *Windows PowerShell*, replace `pwsh` with `powershell`:

```bsh
# Run from PowerShell

# Define the alias.
# Note the unexpected need to escape " as \" - see below.
git config --global alias.unchanged '! pwsh -noprofile -c \"git ls-files -v | sls -pattern ^h -casesensitive\"'

# Invoke it.
git unchanged
```

As an aside: Note the awkward need to `\`-escape the embedded `"` chars., even though they're inside a single-quoted string `'...'` - this unfortunate requirement - which seemingly won't be removed for the sake of backward compatibility - is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361).

---

As for **what you tried**:

Defining your alias as:

> `[alias]
>     unchanged = !git ls-files -v | sls -pattern ^h -casesensitive`

means that `sh` / `bash` is executing the command, as explained above.

While the command is *syntactically* valid there, it fails because `sls` is looked for as an *external program* (given that it is neither a `sh` / `bash` builtin, nor a user-defined function, nor a *`sh` / `bash`* alias), which doesn't exist ("`command not found`").

Only PowerShell knows that `sls` is an alias for the `Select-String` cmdlet (and even using the latter's actual name wouldn't allow it to be called from *outside of PowerShell*, given that it is implemented via a PowerShell-specific *DLL*).

By contrast, `git ls-files -v` by itself works in `sh` / `bash` as well, because it is a call to `git`, an *external program* (a *platform-native executable* that *any* shell can call).