# Git alias with positional parameters in PowerShell

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I have a following [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) command:

```bash
git config --global alias.deploy '!f() { git push origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD):env/$1; unset -f f; }; f'
```

And it works on Linux: when I execute `git deploy myenv`, `myenv` is passed as `$1` value.
However, when I run the same command on Windows (Powershell), it does not work. Tried to use `$args[0]` but it does not seem to work either.

Follows [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters), but for Windows.

Comment: Should work in git-bash. Minor nit: aliases are executed in separate shells, the function `f` disappears immediately when the shell that executes the alias finishes so you don't need `unset -f f`

Comment: The Bash command should work on Windows too, because it is passed to _Git Bash_ (via a `sh.exe` child process), which comes bundled with a Git installation on Windows. That you're calling from PowerShell is therefore incidental (and also explains why you cannot use PowerShell constructs such as `$args[0]`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57978398/45375) for details.

Comment: In what way does it not work? The only potential problem with the definition of `f()` that I see is that it would break with arguments and branch names that contain spaces, due to lack of `"..."` enclosure, though such arguments / names would be unusual (and `myenv` definitely should work).